# Android JNI NDK - No implementation found

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a JNI implementaion of libjpeg-turbo on Android.
Application is built without any problems and I can see inside generated APK file that native `libJPEGProcessing.so` libraries are inside `lib` folder for different architectures.
However, when the native method is invoked through application, I will receive the following "no implementation found" message, which will cause the exception:

```
D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libjpeg.so 0xa4fe3dc0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.google.test-2/libJPEGProcessing.so 0xa4fe3dc0
D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.google.test-2/libJPEGProcessing.so 0xa4fe3dc0
D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.google.test-2/libJPEGProcessing.so 0xa4fe3dc0, skipping init
W/dalvikvm: No implementation found for native Lcom/google/test/NativeMethods;.computeUsableDCTCoefficientsLinkedList:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

This is my methods in JNI:

```
extern "C" {
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Get jclass with env->FindClass.
    // Register methods with env->RegisterNatives.

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_google_test_NativeMethods_computeUsableDCTCoefficientsLinkedList
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString)
{
...
}
}
```

And the generated header file:

```
extern "C" {
/*
 * Class:     com_google_test_NativeMethods
 * Method:    computeUsableDCTCoefficientsLinkedList
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_google_test_NativeMethods_computeUsableDCTCoefficientsLinkedList
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);
}
```

The implementation in Java looks like this:

```
package com.google.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NativeMethods {

    private String filename = null;
    private int fromNative = -100;
    private int numberInList = -100;
    private ArrayList<DCTCoefficient> array = null;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("jpeg");
        System.loadLibrary("JPEGProcessing");
    }

    public static native int computeUsableDCTCoefficientsLinkedList(String filename); 
}
```

This is `Android.mk` for `ndk-build`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_FILES := ./libjpeg-turbo/

LOCAL_MODULE    := JPEGProcessing
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Ic:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\jni\ -Ic:\libjpeg-turbo-gcc\include\
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := JPEGProcessing.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c:\libjpeg-turbo-gcc\lib\libjpeg.a

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

There is no error during building and compiling, application will normally start on Android device. However, I have defined JNI_OnLoad method which is also not called after loading native library in Java class.

**EDIT:**

I found the following warning in Gradle Console which may be related to it:

```
Android NDK: WARNING:C:/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/Test/src/main/jni/Android.mk:JPEGProcessing: non-system libraries in linker flags: c:\libjpeg-turbo-gcc\lib\libjpeg.a    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module
```

**EDIT 2:**

Trying to see inside the compiled libJPEGProcessing.so on Linux:

```
nm libJPEGProcessing.so 
nm: libJPEGProcessing.so: no symbols

nm -D libJPEGProcessing.so 
00002004 A __bss_start
         U __cxa_atexit
         U __cxa_finalize
00002004 A _edata
00002004 A _end
```

There is no exported JNI methods and symbols. Is this correct?

**EDIT 3:**

Output of `ndk-build.cmd -B V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi`:

```
ndk-build.cmd -B V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi
del /f/q c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\libs\arm64-v8a\libJPEGProcessing.so c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\libs\armeabi\libJPEGProcessing.so c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\libs\armeabi-v7a\libJPEGProcessing.so c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\libs\mips\libJPEGProcessing.so c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\libs\mips64\libJPEGProcessing.so c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\libs\x86\libJPEGProcessing.so c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\libs\x86_64\libJPEGProcessing.so >NUL 2>NUL
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libJPEGProcessing.so
C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -Wl,-soname,libJPEGProcessing.so -shared --sysroot=C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-9/arch-arm -lgcc  -gcc-toolchain C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -no-canonical-prefixes -target armv5te-none-linux-androideabi  -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings    -lc -lm -o c:/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/Test/src/main/obj/local/armeabi/libJPEGProcessing.so
[armeabi] Install        : libJPEGProcessing.so => libs/armeabi/libJPEGProcessing.so
copy /b/y "c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\obj\local\armeabi\libJPEGProcessing.so" "c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\libs\armeabi\libJPEGProcessing.so" > NUL
```

Comment: Looks like your code is c++, but Android.mk compiles c. A typo somewhere?

Comment: Actually the code is in c.

Comment: Try using cmake for native build

Comment: I don't know how to convert my ndk build script in `Android.mk` to cmake...but it should work also with ndk build

Comment: **nm -D** shows that your **.so** is not built correctly. Note that `extern "C"` will not compile with C compiler, so look carefully for what went wrong. I suggest that you run `ndk-build -B V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi` (on command line) to see what went wrong with your setup

Comment: `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c:\libjpeg-turbo-gcc\lib\libjpeg.a` is not the way you are expected to express this in **Android.mk**. You should use **PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARIES** for this. But it still looks wrong: your Java code assumes that you use **libjpeg.so**, not the static library.

Comment: @AlexCohn I have added output of `ndk-build -B V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi` to question as **EDIT 3**. There is no error and I do not know where I should look for something that went wrong? Library was compiled.

Comment: Please post `dir /s c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\obj` and `dir /s c:\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\Test\src\main\jni`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok - I could not see any signature problem, and you seems to be loading the library in the required manner. But, the fact is that the log says the library was found, yet it cannot find your JNI_OnLoad implementation. Is there a chance you have more than one version of libJPEGProcessing.so, and the system finds an older one? I'm not talking about different libraries for the various architectures, of course.

Comment: I don't know how to check it, but I have deleted all generated libraries and apk file and built it again. The result is the same.

Comment: The way to check it is to search in the entire project folder. If you have done that, and deleted them all, this is certainly not the issue. There is no point of checking the package and signatures, since clearly the problem here is the library itself (since both onLoad and your method are not found). But your latest edit gives more information - did you try using LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES ?

Comment: I tried using LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES, result the same...at least warning about non-system libraries in linker is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that although the `APK` was compiled and working, the native library wasn't correctly compiled and included inside `APK` file in `lib` folder.

So I changed `build.gradle` to not using `ndk-build`, but instead use pre-compiled native library for the project. After that change, native libraries are included in `APK` and everything is working:

```
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set libs as default directory for .so files inclusion, instead of jniLibs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
```

The only change I have to do is to compile the native library outside the Android Studio if there are any changes.